# Generic repository for generic base class and query for find by key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository, repository-pattern

What I want to do is really simple - I want to create generic repository where generic is generic base Entity where generic on Entity sets type of key. Confuse? Don't be, let's a look at code:

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
    DateTime Create { get; set; }
    DateTime? Storno { get; set; }
}

public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Create { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Storno { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> 
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
{
    protected DbContext context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> database;

    public TEntity Find(TKey id)
    {
        //return database.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id); // <-- Here is how it should look like
        return database.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id.Equals(id)); // <-- Here is problem EF cann't work with this construction
    }
}
```

Exists some solution for this problem? I want avoid hard coded key type for base repository. What just come to my mind is write method Find as virtual (or abstract) and then create special repository for long-key entities, string-key entities, but... It's not solution but just workaround...

Comment: Why don't you reuse existing [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DbSet<T>.Find(params object[] keys)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx) to find entity by key(s):

```
return database.Find(id);
```

Comment: Oh boy... I didn't know about Find method. Thank you works like charm!